# Getting error 500 because of .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new to .htaccess, but have to go this way to protect an image upload folder on a server. I was using the shown script following all the instructions upload works so far, but I am not able to link to the images from the same site now, I get the error "*the server responded with a status 500 (Internal Server Error)*" if I try to access the successfully uploaded file directly (to show it on the site).

The code comes from [here](https://tomolivercv.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/protect-your-uploads-folder-with-htaccess/):

```
IndexIgnore *
AddHandler cgi-script .php .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .php7 .php8 .pl .py .js .jsp .asp .htm .html .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(php\.ini|\.htaccess) - [NC,F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ((php|my|bypass)?shell|remview.*|phpremoteview.*|sshphp.*|pcom|nstview.*|c99|c100|r57|webadmin.*|phpget.*|phpwriter.*|fileditor.*|locus7.*|storm7.*)\.(p?s?x?htm?l?|txt|aspx?|cfml?|cgi|pl|php[3-9]{0,1}|jsp?|sql|xml) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.exe|\.php\?act=|\.tar|_vti|afilter=|algeria\.php|chbd|chmod|cmd|command|db_query|download_file|echo|edit_file|eval|evil_root|exploit|find_text|fopen|fsbuff|fwrite|friends_links\.|ftp|gofile|grab|grep|htshell|\ -dump|logname|lynx|mail_file|md5|mkdir|mkfile|mkmode|MSOffice|muieblackcat|mysql|owssvr\.dll|passthru|popen|proc_open|processes|pwd|rmdir|root|safe0ver|search_text|selfremove|setup\.php|shell|ShellAdresi\.TXT|spicon|sql|ssh|system|telnet|trojan|typo3|uname|unzip|w00tw00t|whoami|xampp) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\.exe|\.tar|act=|afilter=|alter|benchmark|chbd|chmod|cmd|command|cast|char|concat|convert|create|db_query|declare|delete|download_file|drop|edit_file|encode|environ|eval|exec|exploit|find_text|fsbuff|ftp|friends_links\.|globals|gofile|grab|insert|localhost|logname|loopback|mail_file|md5|meta|mkdir|mkfile|mkmode|mosconfig|muieblackcat|mysql|order|passthru|popen|proc_open|processes|pwd|request|rmdir|root|scanner|script|search_text|select|selfremove|set|shell|sql|sp_executesql|spicon|ssh|system|telnet|trojan|truncate|uname|union|unzip|whoami) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpe?g?|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?mysite.com\. [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g?|png|gif)$ - [NC,F]

Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "\.([Jj][Pp][Ee]?[Gg]?|[Pp][Nn][Gg]|[Gg][Ii][Ff])$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch ".*\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<LimitExcept GET POST>
Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

I was searching for other tutorials that fits my targets, but found none... Maybe you could help me edit the one above. Thank you!

**UPDATE**:
So if I disable the lines

```
#AddHandler cgi-script .php .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .php7 .php8 .pl .py .js .jsp .asp .htm .html .shtml .sh .cgi
#Options -ExecCGI -Indexes
```

and

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpe?g?|png|gif)$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?mysite.com\. [NC]
#RewriteRule \.(jpe?g?|png|gif)$ - [NC,F]
```

Then the pictures can be shown, but it is not really my target, as the scripts can still be executed.

Comment: Can you look at your Apache error logs? Have you?

Comment: Yes, is says "[alert] .htaccess: Options not allowed here"

Comment: Well, that would be the reason, the `Options` line is not allowed there by your configuration. Do you *need* that line? *Could* you reconfigure your Apache to allow that line?

Comment: As far as I've understood - it is the line, preventing scripts to be executed, so really critical in my case... No, not possible to reconfigure Apache, as provider does not allow such changes

Answer (score 0):

made some updates to the .htaccess, the final version looks like this, working fine, showing files, does not let the scripts to be executed from the folder.

```html
IndexIgnore *
RemoveHandler .php .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .php7 .php8 .pl .py .js .jsp .asp .htm .html .shtml .sh .cgi
RemoveType .php .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .php7 .php8 .pl .py .js .jsp .asp .htm .html .shtml .sh .cgi
 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(php\.ini|\.htaccess) - [NC,F]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ((php|my|bypass)?shell|remview.*|phpremoteview.*|sshphp.*|pcom|nstview.*|c99|c100|r57|webadmin.*|phpget.*|phpwriter.*|fileditor.*|locus7.*|storm7.*)\.(p?s?x?htm?l?|txt|aspx?|cfml?|cgi|pl|php[3-9]{0,1}|jsp?|sql|xml) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.exe|\.php\?act=|\.tar|_vti|afilter=|algeria\.php|chbd|chmod|cmd|command|db_query|download_file|echo|edit_file|eval|evil_root|exploit|find_text|fopen|fsbuff|fwrite|friends_links\.|ftp|gofile|grab|grep|htshell|\ -dump|logname|lynx|mail_file|md5|mkdir|mkfile|mkmode|MSOffice|muieblackcat|mysql|owssvr\.dll|passthru|popen|proc_open|processes|pwd|rmdir|root|safe0ver|search_text|selfremove|setup\.php|shell|ShellAdresi\.TXT|spicon|sql|ssh|system|telnet|trojan|typo3|uname|unzip|w00tw00t|whoami|xampp) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\.exe|\.tar|act=|afilter=|alter|benchmark|chbd|chmod|cmd|command|cast|char|concat|convert|create|db_query|declare|delete|download_file|drop|edit_file|encode|environ|eval|exec|exploit|find_text|fsbuff|ftp|friends_links\.|globals|gofile|grab|insert|localhost|logname|loopback|mail_file|md5|meta|mkdir|mkfile|mkmode|mosconfig|muieblackcat|mysql|order|passthru|popen|proc_open|processes|pwd|request|rmdir|root|scanner|script|search_text|select|selfremove|set|shell|sql|sp_executesql|spicon|ssh|system|telnet|trojan|truncate|uname|union|unzip|whoami) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !google\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yandex\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !bing\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yahoo\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g?|png|gif)$ - [F]
 
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "\.([Jj][Pp][Ee]?[Gg]?|[Pp][Nn][Gg]|[Gg][Ii][Ff])$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
 
<FilesMatch ".*\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
 
<LimitExcept GET POST>
Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```